# Keras hangs up if creating models via for loop

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras

I am currently confused with the following code snippets: all snippets are part of a [tutorial from here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/weighted-average-ensemble-for-deep-learning-neural-networks/).

I have that function which compiles and fits a new keras model using the Sequential API:

```
def fit_model(trainX, trainy):
    trainy_enc = to_categorical(trainy)
    # define model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(25, input_dim=2, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    # fit model
    model.fit(trainX, trainy_enc,epochs=200, verbose=0)
    return model
```

I now want to create e.g. 10 models using a shorthander to create, compile and fit the models and store them in a list:

```
n_members = 10
members = [fit_model(trainX, trainy) for _ in range(n_members)]
```

The issue is that Keras (randomly) seems to hang up and the training progress does not continue any more. Its really total randomly, sometimes it happens at the first model to create, sometimes at the fifth. And the epochs it hangs are also arbitrarily.

How can I get out of this problem? I am not sure, everything is implemented as in the source tutorial and there it seems to work that way.

Comment: Are you using tensorflow as backend? Which version? If you're using 2.0 maybe try going back to tf1.

Comment: yes iam using tf 2.0 but i also tried the downgrade to tf 1.15 and it causes the same issue